# Average wind data in python (10-10minutes for hourly)

Tags: python, excel

I have wind data measured every 10 minutes, in a time of approximately 3 months, and to do Wind Rose I need to "simplify" this data, therefore, to average the winds for every 1 hour. To do this, I opened the file '.data' or '.txt' that was like this
[.data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InIjy.jpg)

And I separated the columns in excel by dividing the data and excluding what I would not use, thus ...
[excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1GSp.jpg)

In Excel I decomposed the wind vector into X and Y as follows:

> WindDirDegree * (Pi / 180) = WindDirRad
>
> Xwind = WindSpd * sin (WindDirRad)
>
> Ywind = WindSpd * cos (WindDirRad)

Now I need to upload this data in python, read it correctly for the raw file or the already separated file, have it identify the dates and times and the measurements, and average for the Xwind and Ywind data at the same time (hour by hour) . Just exporting this already would save my life, which then step back to wind in degrees and already I can do the rose of the winds in the wrplot.
Can anyone help me?

> EDIT
>   I can import the file, I just can not get it to identify the dates, identify the same hours, and command to do the X and Y averages.
>
> i have one old script but i dont understand

import pandas as pd

from datetime import datetime as dt

parse = lambda x: dt.strptime(x, '%Y %m %d %H %M')

meu_df = pd.read_excel('./teste.xlsx', parse_dates=[['YYYY', 'MM',
                       'DD',  'HH',  'MM.1']], index_col=0, date_parser=parse)

meu_df.between_time('11:00','11:59')

meu_df[meu_df.index.hour == 10]

horas = set(meu_df.index.hour.values)

for hora in horas:
  print('hora = {}'.format(hora))
  a = meu_df[meu_df.index.hour == hora].mean()
  print(a)

meu_df[meu_df.index.hour == 10].mean()

media_wspd = meu_df['WSPD'].between_time('11:00','11:59').mean()

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking.  Are you asking how to read your .txt file with python?

Comment: Chapter 330 and 475 of pythons cookbook (2nd eds) shows this in detail. Conversion to XML is inevitable i.m.o. Rather old solutions though! Another solution is to read [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/csv.html?highlight=excel) the csv solution.

Answer (score 0):

I see your new to python and just after some help I think you should go look at a library of python called pandas. You can do everything you talk about in your post read in the original data which just looks like a csv file

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("filename.data")
```

will help you start, then you can aggregate and do all the manipulation you need